# Using DateTime and split in Array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, object, split

I'm trying to to take part of a string and set it as a date time property for a class. The date part of string is part of a textfile and formatted as `dd/mm/yyyy`.

My code works fine for other properties, string int etc but I'm experiencing an error when trying to use datetime. I cant pinpoint where the problem is.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in Hospital.exe
>
> Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.''

```
//read files from file
string[] linesx = File.ReadAllLines("patients.txt");//creates array of each line in text file
string[] patientInfo = new string[4];
string[] dateInfo = new string[3];
string patientLong, name;
Patient newPatient;
int age,blood,x;
DateTime date;
int year, month, day;

//sort through text and get data.
for (int i = 0; i < linesx.Length; i++)
{
    patientLong = linesx[i];//gets each lines details eg.ward,56
    patientInfo = patientLong.Split(',');//separates info eg,ward   ,56  
    name = patientInfo[0];//gets name from index 0
    age = Convert.ToInt32(patientInfo[1]);  //gets age from index1                       
    blood = Convert.ToInt32(patientInfo[2]);
    x = Convert.ToInt32(patientInfo[3]);

    dateInfo = patientInfo[2].Split('/');
    day = Convert.ToInt32(dateInfo[0]);
    month = Convert.ToInt32(dateInfo[1]);
    year = Convert.ToInt32(dateInfo[2]);

    date = new DateTime(year, month, day);




    newPatient = new Patient(name, age,blood,x,date);
    patients.Add(newPatient);
}
```

Comment: You use patientinfo[2] as the string for the date, but the same string has been used previously for another info [blood]

Comment: In any case, writing code that tries to access indexes of an array without being sure the array has the required number of elements is a recipe for this kind of error

Comment: Thank you, my brain is melted. Such a simple solution !

Comment: `dateInfo = patientInfo[2].Split('/')` <- are you sure `patientInfo[2]` really contains a `\` to split by?

Comment: Could you provide an extract from the `patients.txt` file, please?

Comment: JoeWalsh,99,1,0,10/10/1980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that

```
dateInfo = patientInfo[2].Split('/');
```

should be

```
dateInfo = patientInfo[4].Split('/');
```

Comment: Thanks. Its becomes difficult to spot small errors when youve worked at something for a while

Answer (score 0):

You've messed `int` and `DateTime` formats:

Either `patientInfo[2]` is `integer`, e.g. `42`, so you can put

```
  blood = Convert.ToInt32(patientInfo[2]);
```

but can't

```
  dateInfo = patientInfo[2].Split('/');
  month = Convert.ToInt32(dateInfo[1]);
```

Or `patientInfo[2]` is `DateTime`, e.g. `10/11/1976`, so you can't put

```
 blood = Convert.ToInt32(patientInfo[2]);
```

Since you have 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException`exception,`patientInfo[2]`is of type`int`and the most probable cause of the misbehaviour is a *typo*: it's`patientInfo[4]`that stores`date`, not`patientInfo[2]`.

As for implementation, it's one of the problem **Linq** has been designed for:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ....

 List<Patient> patients = File
   .ReadLines("patients.txt")
   .Select(line => line.Split(','))
   .Select(items => new Patient(
      items[0],
      int.Parse(items[1]),
      int.Parse(items[2]), 
      int.Parse(items[3]),
      DateTime.ParseExact(items[4], "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)   
     ))
   .ToList();
```